# ActionView::Template::Error::(no implicit conversion of symbol into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, implicit-conversion

In my log i am getting this error.
log is pointing to line number 3 of html code which is

line3- `<%= form_for @user ,user_addphno_path(@user) do |f|  %>`

```
   <%= f.label :PhoneNumber %><br />
```

line6- `<%= f.text_field :phno, autofocus: true %>`

line7- `<%= f.submit "Update" %>`

My form has only one field phno and submit button .

my log file look like
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

```
1: Update

2: 
3: <%= form_for @user ,user_addphno_path(@user) do |f|  %>
4:    
5: <div class="field">
6:     <%= f.label :PhoneNumber %><br />
```

app/views/addphno/addphno.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_addphno_addphno_html_erb___890059295_77273976'

Comment: thanks for correction..

Comment: any idea why i am getting this error.

Comment: Cn you post your full error log and full form code in the question?

Comment: this is my form ... <h2>Update</h2>

<%= form_for @user ,user_addphno_path(@user) do |f|  %>
   
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :PhoneNumber %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phno, autofocus: true %>
  </div> 
  <br />
  

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

Comment: I said to post it in the question.

Comment: it should be `form_for @user, url: user_addphno_path(@user)`

Comment: thanks for reply , i changed the syntax as u mentioned . Now no error but still phno field is not getting saved into database

Comment: Started PATCH "/users/25/addphno" for ::1 at 2015-10-24 21:12:41 +0530
Processing by AddphnoController#addphno as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1WjQsa/oXGl79+xKFPgyZV52XqHl2BVNQsN0KVVxdD6NDxdvgMETldv4C2UwgcO8kO650z5V6YSO0jiawZwaig==", "user"=>{"phno"=>"123"}, "commit"=>"Update", "user_id"=>"25"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (4.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 25 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered addphno/addphno.html.erb (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 40.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)

Comment: it seems update statment not triggering .as in log mysql update statment is not there ,do not why ..

Comment: Started PATCH "/users/34/addphno" for ::1 Processing by AddphnoController#addphno as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z/oB01ipXhhQvxUtkyJmIDZ4jxANJbRmiVcPacPfTntskL4YL8Yrx1uzj‌​pw2l3mNEBUxapOMb/lefs0i89ooww==", "user"=>{"phno"=>"8888"}, "commit"=>"Update", "user_id"=>"34"} [SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.id = 34 LIMIT 1 UPDATE users SET users.phno = NULL WHERE users.id = 34 Rendered addphno/addphno.html.erb (5.0ms) Completed 200 OK in 107ms (Views: 50.0ms | ActiveRecord: 48.0ms)

Comment: phno field is submitting in parameters section when in mysql update it is going null ..any idea

Comment: Any help.i m badly looking for a solution